# How to set routing between CI and Laravel

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, routes

I have two different modules one is codeigniter module and second one is laravel5 module.

My Question

> Is it possible to set a common routing between these two module ?

I am using `CI v2.2.6` and `Laravel 5.0` I have tried with `.htaccess` but I am unable to perform what I want.

I have some pages in `CI` module Ex:

```
/home
/login
/signup
/otherPages
```

I have some pages in `laravel` Ex:

```
/product
/buy
/edit
/otherPages
```

Now I want to access

```
 mywebsite.com/home
 mywebsite.com/product
 and all
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . control.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

creat file control.php

```
 #split the path by '/'
  $params     = split("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    define("FILE_PHP",".php");
    define("ERROR_404","404.php");
    define("INCLUDE_ADMIN","index.php");
    class Loader{

     public function __autoload($params) {
         if(isset($params[1])==TRUE){ 
          if (file_exists($params[1].FILE_PHP)) { 
              require_once $params[1].FILE_PHP; 
              return true; 
          } 
           require_once ERROR_404; 
          return false; 
         }else{
          require_once INCLUDE_ADMIN; 
          return TRUE; 
         }
    } 
    }
    $loader=new Loader();
    $loader->__autoload ($params);
```